# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, setstate

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class Clock extends React.Component 
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        //defining state
        this.state={date:new Date()};
    }

    updateTime()
    {
        //updating the time by set state
        this.setState( (state,props) =>  {date:new Date()}  );
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Now the time is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>
                <button onClick={this.updateTime}>Update Time</button>
        
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Clock;
```

Getting below error on updating the state i.e. when the button is clicked.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined updateTime
>   C:/Users/YV/YVSCodes/React-Van/hi-app/src/setState-event-binding-exampleComponent.js:21
>   18 |    updateTime()    19 |    {    20 |        //updating the time
>   by set state
>
> > 21 |        this.setState( (state,props) =>  {date:new Date()}  );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind updateTime

```
constructor(props) {
   ...
   this.updateTime = this.updateTime.bind(this)
}
```

or use arrow function

```
updateTime = () => {
    //updating the time by set state
    this.setState( (state,props) =>  {date:new Date()}  );
}
```

and change your setState to

```
this.setState({
  date: new Date()
});
```

or

```
this.setState( (state,props) =>  ({date:new Date()})  );
```

Comment: None of them are working bro. They've removed the error, but the onClick functionality isn't working on add those

Comment: you can check here [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-water-oqj4e)

Comment: update answer, you forget to return object in your setState, you can fix to `this.setState( (state,props) => { return {date:new Date()} } );` or as my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
updateTime() {
    //updating the time by set state
    this.setState( (state,props) =>  {date:new Date()}  );
}
```

with this

```
updateTime = () => {
    this.setState((state, props) => {
        return {
          date: new Date()
        };
    });
};
```